# lottie-animation inside div bleeding/overflowing onto another div (overflow: hidden/clip doesn't work)

Tags: html, css, overflow, lottie

Besides the fact that i just started learning html and am a bit in over my head with this project. I created a lottie animation and am trying to use it as a background for the homepage, contained in the yellow background, but it keeps bleeding onto the div below it

this is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>addup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
    <div class="masthead">
      <div class="animation">
        <lottie-player
          src="https://lottie.host/fe94f5fb-c303-472e-943e-673b0384863a/TmpectQW9D.json"
          class="bg-animation"
          background="transparent"
          speed="0.1"
          loop
          autoplay
          width="1000px"
        ></lottie-player>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <lottie-player
          src="https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_3YNOdXZTuL.json"
          class="logo-animation"
          background="transparent"
          autoplay
          speed="0.5"
        ></lottie-player>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    <div class="video">
      <video autoplay muted loop src="Comp 1.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*, *::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.masthead {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    clear: both;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    background: linear-gradient(124deg, #fcff89, #fcff89, #ffffff, #fcff89, #ffffff, #fcff89, #fcff89, #fcff89, #ffffff);
    background-size: 1800% 1800%;
    -webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
    animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
}

.masthead .logo .logo-animation {
    width: 400px;
}

.masthead .animation {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-bottom: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.masthead .animation .bg-animation {
    width: 400%;
    transform: translate(-25%, -25%);
    opacity: 0.5;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
}

.video {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(62, 157, 24);
    background-color: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow { 
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
```

The animation is targeted in

```
.masthead .animation .bg-animation
```

I tried using overflow:hidden or overflow:clip on all the animation elements and on the div to no avail. What should i do?